# In tensorflow/keras, why train_on_batch output loss is different when recomputed after training using predict_on_batch?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I created a model using keras and I trained it using `train_on_batch`. To check if the model does what it's supposed to do, I recomputed the loss before and after the training phase using the `predict_on_batch` method. But, as you'd guess when reading the title, I don't have the same output losses.

Here follows a basic code to illustrate my problem:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 

# Loss definition
def mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true-y_pred))

# Model definition
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile('rmsprop',mse)

# Data creation
batch_size = 10
x = np.random.random_sample([batch_size,10])
y = np.random.random_sample(batch_size)

# Print loss before training
y_pred = model.predict_on_batch(x)
print("Before: " + str(mse(y,y_pred).numpy()))

# Print loss output from train_on_batch
print("Train output: " + str(model.train_on_batch(x,y)))

# Print loss after training
y_pred = model.predict_on_batch(x)
print("After: " + str(mse(y,y_pred).numpy()))
```

With this code I get the following outputs:

```
Before: 0.28556848
Train output: 0.29771945
After: 0.27345362
```

I'd suppose that the training loss and the loss computed after training should be the same. So I'd like to understand why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is how `train_on_batch` works, it calculates the loss, then updates the network, so we get the loss before the network was updated.
When we apply `predict_on_batch`, we get the prediction from the updated network.**

Under the hood, train_on_batch does many more things like fixing your data types, standardizing your data, etc.

The closest sibling of `train_on_batch` would be `test_on_batch`. If you run `test_on_batch` you'll find the result is close to `train_on_bacth` but not same.

Here's an implementation of `test_on_batch` : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e5bf8de410005de06a7ff5393fafdf832ef1d4ad/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py#L442

it internally calls `_standardize_user_data` to fix your data types, data shapes, etc.

Once, you fix your `x` and `y` with proper shapes and data types the result is very close except for some small difference `delta` due to numerical instability.

Here's a minimal example where the `test_on_batch`, `train_on_batch` and `predict_on_batch` seem to agree on the result numerically.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 

# Loss definition
def mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true-y_pred))

# Model definition
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_shape = (10,)))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = mse, metrics = [mse])

# Data creation
batch_size = 10
x = np.random.random_sample([batch_size,10]).astype('float32').reshape(-1, 10)
y = np.random.random_sample(batch_size).astype('float32').reshape(-1,1)

print(x.shape)
print(y.shape)

model.summary()

# running 5 iterations to check
for _ in range(5):

  # Print loss before training
  y_pred = model.predict_on_batch(x)
  print("Before: " + str(mse(y,y_pred).numpy()))

  # Print loss output from train_on_batch
  print("Train output: " + str(model.train_on_batch(x,y)))

  print(model.test_on_batch(x, y))

  # Print loss after training
  y_pred = model.predict_on_batch(x)
  print("After: " + str(mse(y,y_pred).numpy()))
```

```
(10, 10)
(10, 1)
Model: "sequential_25"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_27 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 11        
=================================================================
Total params: 11
Trainable params: 11
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
Before: 0.30760005
Train output: [0.3076000511646271, 0.3076000511646271]
[0.3052913546562195, 0.3052913546562195]
After: 0.30529135
Before: 0.30529135
Train output: [0.3052913546562195, 0.3052913546562195]
[0.30304449796676636, 0.30304449796676636]
After: 0.3030445
Before: 0.3030445
Train output: [0.30304449796676636, 0.30304449796676636]
[0.3008604645729065, 0.3008604645729065]
After: 0.30086046
Before: 0.30086046
Train output: [0.3008604645729065, 0.3008604645729065]
[0.2987399995326996, 0.2987399995326996]
After: 0.29874
Before: 0.29874
Train output: [0.2987399995326996, 0.2987399995326996]
[0.2966836094856262, 0.2966836094856262]
After: 0.2966836
```

***N.B: `train_on_batch` updates the weight of the neural network after calculating the loss, so obviously the loss from `train_on_batch` and `test_on_batch` or `predict_on_batch` won't be same exactly. The proper question could be why `test_on_batch` and `predict_on_batch` give different losses with your data.***

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Zabir Al Nazi, I understood the problem: keras `predict_on_batch` output differs from `test_on_batch` and `train_on_batch` due to the additional standardization that is done on the data.

If `predict_on_batch` has to be used, the data has to be standardized before (at least in tersorflow 2.1.0 but it will probably be edited later). It can be done manually or with the `_standardize_user_data` function.

Here follows my previous code corrected by using this function:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np 

# Loss definition
def mse(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true-y_pred))

# Model definition
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile('rmsprop',mse)

# Data creation
batch_size = 10
x = np.random.random_sample([batch_size,10])
y = np.random.random_sample(batch_size)

# STANDARDIZATION
tmp_x,tmp_y,_ = model._standardize_user_data(x,y)
x,y = tmp_x[0], tmp_y[0]

# Print loss before training
y_pred = model.predict_on_batch(x)
print("Before: " + str(mse(y,y_pred).numpy()))

# Print loss output from train_on_batch
print("Train output: " + str(model.train_on_batch(x,y)))

# Print loss after training
y_pred = model.predict_on_batch(x)
print("After: " + str(mse(y,y_pred).numpy()))
```

This will give the appropriate output:

```
Before: 0.425879
Train output: 0.425879
After: 0.4123691
```